# GTEST : Identify before and after a SetUp and TearDown respectively

Tags: c++, googletest

I have multiple Test Classes each have their SetUp() and TearDown().

From what I have read the sequence for running test cases after RUN_ALL_TEST() is not known.

I want to start a service before the first SetUp called and stop the service after the last TearDown is called.

How do I achieve that?
An Example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First observation is that these are not Unit Tests, since they require "services" to be running. I suggest considering redesigning the application to allow tests to be run without the need for external services. One approach might be to use abstract classes and google mock.

The problem with having an external service that survives the normal `TearDown` is that it becomes your explicit responsibility to ensure that the next test will find a clean environment: a test can be broken by state set by a previous test.

If you really want to go down the route of long-lived external services, read about `SetUpTestCase` and `TearDownTestCase` in the [gtest advanced guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md), that will allow to start the service only once per test fixture.

There is an even more dangerous `Environment` class that allows to do global setup and teardown (search in the advanced guide).

But again, your tests will be brittle and hard to debug. I suggest reconsidering the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::call_once` to ensure sonething gets called only once.